# Scroll to top and addClass onClick - then removeClass on .mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function is to click a button, the browser window then scrolls to the top of the page, then a class is added to a menu item (with CSS to make the sub menu appear). Then when the cursor leaves the sub menu, the class is removed to allow the sub menu to disappear.

Can I make the following code shorter or more efficient? I have written it to work with Joomla and jQuery with no conflict.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#instruct-us-readmore").click(function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 800);
        setTimeout(
        function() {
            jQuery("#iceMenu_144 ul.sub_level_1").addClass("instruct-button-click");
        },950);


     });
});


  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#iceMenu_144 ul.sub_level_1").mouseleave(function(){
            jQuery("#iceMenu_144 ul.sub_level_1").removeClass("instruct-button-click");
    });
      });
```

Comment: shorter is not necessarily more efficient...

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Ok, so you wouldn't suggest any amendments?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides itself as first argument in the ready callback. You can assign it the `$` name so you can use it shorthand inside the callback.

```
jQuery(function($){
  // Use jQuery as $ inside here
});
```

Also, you don't need multiple ready handlers. Whenever possible, just bunch them up into one.

```
jQuery(function($){
  // Click handler
  // Mouse handler
});
```

Next is that we don't know for certain how `jquery.animate` schedules animation. This might affect how sooner or later the callback for `setTimeout` is executed.

However, `jquery.animate` accepts a function as the last argument which is run when the animation is complete. Use that instead of doing a timeout.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 800, function(){
  // done animating
});
```